# Is that possible to create eclipse custom Toolbar(set the height and grouping toolbar items vertically)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Can someone help me out to create custom toolbar similar in MS-Word see the image below for reference.

1. Is that really possible to increase the height of the eclipse tool bar?
2. I need to add few ToolBar items in a group with horizontally and vertically(similar to cut, copy Paste toolbar items).

[image]

I have tried by creating custom control for the toolbar menucontribution

```
This in my plugin.xml

<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
      <toolbar
            id="com.ancit.custom.toolbar.id1">
         <command
               commandId="com.ancit.custom.toolbar.commands.foo"
               label="Foo"
               style="push">
         </command>
         <command
               commandId="com.ancit.custom.toolbar.commands.bar"
               label="Bar"
               style="push">
         </command>
         <control
               class="com.ancit.custom.toobar.ui.action.NewControlContribution">
         </control>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

And my control class wold be like this:

```
public class NewControlContribution extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

    private LabelContributionItem ipLabel;

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
        setupContributionItems();

        ToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager();
        manager.add(ipLabel);
        ToolBar toolBar = manager.createControl(parent);
        // Highlight the ToolBar in red.
        toolBar.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

        return toolBar;
    }

    private void setupContributionItems() {
        ipLabel = new LabelContributionItem("ipLabel", SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    }

}
```

And the implementation for the ToolBar item will be

```
public class LabelContributionItem extends ControlContribution {

    private final int style;
    private Composite composite;

    public LabelContributionItem(String id) {
        this(id, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    }

    public LabelContributionItem(String id, int style) {
        super(id);
        this.style = style;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
        composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);


        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 4;
        composite.setLayout(gridLayout);

        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < 8; loopIndex++) {
            Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("Button " + loopIndex);
        }

        return composite;
    }

    @Override
    public int computeWidth(Control control) {
        return 500;
    }

    public Composite getLabelControl() {
        return composite;
    }
}
```

[image]

But seems like the height is not increasing as according to 8 buttons

Comment: The ToolBar height should adjust according to its contents. You can add other controls to a ToolBar so I imagine you could add a vertical ToolBar. I do not have any example code.

Comment: That's kind of toolbar is called [_Ribbon_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29) and as far as I know, some have already implemented this for Eclipse, or at least tried to.

Comment: @gerg-449, I tried to add custom control to a ToolBar which creates 8 buttons, as per you comment it has to 4 buttons each in 2 rows vertically, but its showing only 4 buttons, rest of them were hidden.

Comment: @howlger, If you found any reference for Ribbon ToolBar would be appreciate.

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://github.com/Raccoonwao/ribbonide). If I remember correctly, there was once the proposal to publish Ribbon for Eclipse as part of the Eclipse Nebula project, but this failed for licensing reasons.

Comment: Might be [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471313)